# Help With Washer Drain Pipe

Tags: drain, washing-machine, installation

I have to install a washer on the second floor of a new home we purchased. I'm comfortable with the water lines, but I'm not 100% clear on the drain line and don't want to make a mistake.

There's an elbow joint on the floor behind the washer spot. I've got no idea what it is for. Then there's the hole next to the intake lines. Every tutorial/video I've watched says the hole in the wall for the drain line. What is the pipe on the floor for and does the drain line definitely run to the hole next to the water supply lines?

[image]

[image]

[More photos](https://imgur.com/a/EvUl8aZ)

Comment: Is that floor pipe possibly for a central vacuum system?

Comment: I don't think so. It's not like any I've ever seen and it looks too small.

Answer (score 3):

The connection in the floor is for a washing machine drain pan. You put it under the washing machine and connect the pipe in the floor through the hole in the back of the drain pan. If your washing machine leaks, then it will drain through that pipe.

Comment: He's right about the drain pan. I wasn't thinking of that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely forgot about that as an option.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the washer should drain into the standpipe which is located next to the supply. Based on how nasty it looks, it's been used. I can't help you with what's in the floor... it isn't big enough to drain a washing machine.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I went with it and it seems to have worked out. I appreciate the confirmation and support.